# MaxScript Bitmap UI - loading bitmaps and formats questions

Tags: user-interface, bitmap, maxscript

I am newbie with maxscript and I would like to ask few questions about Bitmap UI.

```
rollout BitmapTestRollout "Bitmap" width:100 height:100
(
    bitmap mybitmap1 "Bitmap" pos:[25,25] width:50 height:50 fileName:"error_i.bmp"
)
```

I have this simple bitmap rollout and I have few questions about it:

Is there a way to load png images instead of bmp? I've used also `imgtag.bitmap` instead of `bitmap` but it also didn't work. 
Can I load bitmaps from external directories and where are all max-default available bitmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any image file max is able to read. Instead of using `filename` keword parameter use `bitmap` keyword parameter and a bitmap value (you can get one using openBitmap), for example:

```
bitmap mybitmap1 "Bitmap" pos:[25,25] width:50 height:50 bitmap:(openBitmap @"C:\temp.png")
```

As for the bitmaps available when using the filename parameter, this is what [maxscript reference](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_F9F2AE47_958E_4B5E_86F3_17C92A69C66C_htm) has to say about it:

> The specified file name is searched for in the following directories
>   (in order of search): current MAXScript directory, MAXScript startup
>   directory, MAXScript directory, 3ds Max bitmap directories, and then
>   the 3ds Max image directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that i prefer is:
i think this was is easier to manage and reuse in more ways.

```
    -- your bitmap
    local thumb_1 = "D:\\someimage.png"
    local thumb1 = openBitMap(thumb_1)
    imgTag thumbnail1 "logo" style:#bmp_center bitmap:thumb1 pos:[360,05] width:200 height:170
```